# What is the best way to determine how much time for an EMR job is spent on Map vs Reduce Tasks?

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I am running a custom jar hadoop job in Amazon's AWS EMR, and I want to gather data on how much time is spent running all Map tasks vs time spent running Reduce tasks. Is there a way in the framework to mine this data that I have not found? If not does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to generate this data?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can find this info in the Job Counters section of the client logs. For eg :

```
Job Counters 
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=7
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1071855
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=4083210
        **Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=23819**
        **Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=45369**
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=23819
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=45369
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=34299360
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=130662720
Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=3929235
        Map output records=15716940
        Map output bytes=132989251
        Map output materialized bytes=633590
        Input split bytes=86
```